# Retrieving an array from an online database and pulling back into android studio to an array for populating a spinner

Tags: java, php, android

Ok so I've been searching to find the answer to the problem I'm having but I can't seem to find the exact answer i need to get my code working. What I need to do seems pretty easy but doesn't work. I have an database on a server and I need to take the records from that and put them in an array, then pass them back over to android studio. From their they need to populate into a spinner. Here is the .php file and the code I'm trying to get work.. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I know the .php file is working properly the java end in android studio is where I really need the help.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM StateDetails");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $stateID, $statename);

$state = array();
$stateid = array();
$counter = 0;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $state[$stateID] = $statename;
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}

echo json_encode($state);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

---

Java Code:

```
public class fetchStateDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, States>{
    States states;
    GetStatesCallback statesCallback;
    private String[] stateArray;

    public fetchStateDataAsyncTask(States states, GetStatesCallback statesCallback) {
        this.states = states;
        this.statesCallback = statesCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected States doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchStateData.php");

        States returnedStates = null;

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(get);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);



            stateArray = new String[jArray.length()];

            for(int i = 1; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                stateArray[i] = jArray.getString(i);
            }

            returnedStates = new States(jArray.length(), stateArray);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Log.d("States", stateArray.toString());
        return returnedStates;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(States returnedStates) {
        super.onPostExecute(returnedStates);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        statesCallback.done(returnedStates);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `Log.d`'s output ?

Comment: It's not showing anything.. I'm guessing because it's in the doInBackground..

Comment: what response u getting when u call server? and post the response